# Formatting the print of a path in 2d grid

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting

I have a 2d grid and a path through the grid like so:

```
grid = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
path = [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

My desired result is a nicely formatted output depicting the grid with the path shown:

```
  *1   2   3
  *4   5   6
  *7  *8  *9
```

Being new to Python, I do not fully know how to use list comprehensions and string formatting to my advantage.

Here is what I have so far:

```
def print_path(grid, path):
    print('\n'.join(''.join(['{:4}'.format(val) for val in row]) for row in grid))

--- Output ---

   1   2   3
   4   5   6
   7   8   9
```

My ideas for getting the asterisks before the specific elements in the path is to map the actual grid elements to the string representation that should be used in the result, so:

```
1 => "*1"
2 => "2"
...
9 => "*9"
```

Overall, the syntax of Python feels overwhelming. I am trying to write more like a Python-er would as opposed to a Java-er (what I'm comfortable with). Any tips / hints / solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a nested list comprehension and a dictionary that helps you to choose a star in case that the index is in your path or otherwise an empty string.

```
In [36]: choose = {True: '*', False:''}
In [37]: print('\n'.join([' '.join(["{}{}".format(choose[(ind, i) in path], j) for i, j in enumerate(sub)]) for ind, sub in enumerate(grid)]))
*1  2  3
*4  5  6
*7 *8 *9


#Here is the broken version for more readability:

#'\n'.join([' '.join(
#          ["{}{}".format(choose[(ind, i) in path], j)
#           for i, j in enumerate(sub)])
#    for ind, sub in enumerate(grid)])
```

Comment: I would break it up for readability sake. If someone else was ever trying to edit or add on to this, they would have a hard time understanding what this is. +1 though.

Comment: @AdamSuskin if this helped you out, please mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: @PikeD. I am trying to make sure I understand it before accepting, but yes it clearly does what it is supposed to do! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
def grid_counter(grid, path):
    for row, row_list in enumerate(grid):
        for column, column_num in enumerate(row_list):
            if (row, column) in path:
                print("*"+str(column_num), end=" ")
            else:
                print(str(column_num), end=" ")
        print("\n")
```

Here is a longer version. You could simplfy it, and use list comp.

Answer (score 0):

and the "unreadable" one liner

```
def print_path(grid, path):
    print('\n'.join(
            ''.join(['{:4}'.format('*' * ((i,j) in path) + str(val))
                     for j, val in enumerate(row)])
           for i, row in enumerate(grid)))

print_path(grid, path)
*1  2   3   
*4  5   6   
*7  *8  *9
```